# How to generate SSL certificate & public key for encryption?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I am working with some XYZ API provider.

What they are asking is the following:

- Certificate with 4096 bits public key for encryption (.pem or .cer
  format)
- SSL certificate for sending callback response on call back URL.

I generated the self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL & shared with them along with the private key (I know we shouldn't). They asked me to share a valid public key & SSL certificate.

I even generated a certificate & private key on DigiCert, but couldn't figure out how to generate a public key for SSL Certificate.

Can anyone kindly suggest how to generate Public key & private key for the SSL Certificate?

Kindly also suggest if I can use Comodo or DigiCert to generate a public key for the SSL certificate?

Comment: You didn't generate a private key. You generated a key pair, consisting of public and private.

Comment: NB 'for encryption' is not correct. The public key in an SSL certificate is usually only used for verification. SSL certificate authorities frequently get this wrong, and in general provide all sorts of misinformation as to what they are selling and how it all works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SSL Certificate **is** a public key verified and signed by a *Certificate Authority*. You generate a public/private key pair, then from that generate a [Certificate Signing Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (which **includes** the public key), which you send to the *CA*. It then signs that public key included in the *CSR* producing the **certificate** which it sends back to you. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Issuing_a_certificate).

It sounds like you already have this though, so you'd need to clarify what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like it may be a client authentication / mutual authentication scenario? If so, it depends on what the service provider requires - certificates for client authentication may need to be signed either by a public authority that the server trusts, or by the server itself.